# Firefox not loading all cookies from cookies.sqlite saved in profile directory

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, cookies

I opened Firefox browser instance using selenium using gecko driver. All the cookies are first saved into a custom profile directory in the **cookies.sqlite** table. When looking over the table, there are specifically two cookie names:

a. **1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username** and

b. **1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity**

Every other option is same for both of the cookies. Like **expiry, httpOnly** option etc. But why is the browser loading **1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username** and not **1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_identity**? What determines to load or not load the cookie saved in cookies.sqlite?